# Language policies in education for Friesland

Tags: language-acquisition, code-switching, dutch

Friesland is a region in northern Netherlands where the Frisian language is spoken. As part of the Netherlands, Dutch is also spoken. So for natives of Frisian language there should be an educative option so they can master the rules of their language.

How's this achieved? Do the public schools enforce some kind of time proportion of language use or compulsory languages for courses?

Comment: I am interested in this, but I'm not convinced it has anything to do with linguistics, which is the scientific study of language. It would be on topic on the [Languages.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61823) for sure though.

Comment: Many linguistics would include language policy as a branch of the study of the social aspects of language use. For example, the [Cambridge Handbook of Language Policy](http://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/sociolinguistics/cambridge-handbook-language-policy) appeared in the Cambridge Handbooks in Language and Linguistics series.

Comment: For primary schools in Friesland, Frisian is a required course. There are also some bilingual primary schools. No requirements, for secondary schools and higher 
See https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweetalig_onderwijs#Fries and http://taal.phileon.nl/fry_onderwijs.php (both in Dutch)